# Making Upcalls from JavaScript to JavaFX

Tags: java, javascript, webview, javafx, fullcalendar

I'm trying to call a JavaScript function `testCheckMate` from Java but I get error:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" netscape.javascript.JSException: SyntaxError: Unexpected EOF
```

The WebView is holding [FullCalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/).

How do I go about calling JQuery/ Javascript from Java? Thank you all in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href='../fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
        <link href='../fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
        <script src='../lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script src='../lib/jquery-ui.custom.min.js'></script>
        <script src='../fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
        <script>

            $(document).ready(function() {

                var date = new Date();
                var d = date.getDate();
                var m = date.getMonth();
                var y = date.getFullYear();

                $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                        editable: true,

                    testCheckMate: function() {
                        alert("Check-Mate");
                    },

                    events: [
                        {
                            title: 'All Day Event',
                            start: new Date(y, m, 1)
                        },
                        {
                            id: 999,
                            title: 'Repeating Event',
                            start: new Date(y, m, d + 4, 16, 0),
                            allDay: false
                        }
                    ]
                });

            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='calendar'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get this right, you want to send some data from JavaScript when the user clicks on some of the items of the calendar.

First, you should give a name to the JavaScript property different from the actual name of function `eventClick`, like: `myClick`. Then pass a new instance of `JavaApp`:

```
script.setMember("myClick", new JavaApp());
```

where `JavaApp` should be public, and its method should receive the messages from JS. (EDIT: You can define several arguments):

```
public class JavaApp {

    public void javaApp(String title, String x, String y, String name) {
        System.out.println("Event Title: "+title+", Coordinates ("+x+", "+y+"), view Name: "+name);
    }
}
```

Finally, on the JavaScript side, inside the `eventClick` function, use the JS property sent from JavaFX and its method to send the data to the Java side:

```
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

    myClick.javaApp(calEvent.title, jsEvent.pageX, jsEvent.pageY, view.name);

    // change the border color just for fun
    $(this).css('border-color', 'red');

};
```

Comment: You can define several arguments on your `javaApp` method. Note that you can't define `Object event`,... since those are JavaScript objects, and the argument recevied on the Java side will be of the type `JSObject`, and you won't be able to get anything from there. You can define several `String` arguments, though. I edit my answer with this last option.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @José Pereda. Your post has been of great help. However, I can only get the borders changed to red, but can't get access to the event: this `myClick.javaApp('Event: ' + calEvent.title);` does not get called.

Comment: If the border changes to red, then the call is well processed (check your Java console), otherwise you won't see the red border.

Comment: Thank you so much @José Pereda. The edit works like a charm. My internet here is really bad so I get your responses a bit late. Again, thank you so much.